# Passing Node.JS res to a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameter-passing, restify

This doesn't show any response to an HTTP request, just hangs:

```
function middleware(req, res, next) {
    to_end(res).NotFound();
    return next();
}
```

This works:

```
function middleware(req, res, next) {
    to_end(res).NotFound();
    res.send(); // <----------------------------------------------
    return next();
}
```

I'm using restify with this simple function:

```
export const to_end = res => {
    return {
        NotFound: (entity = 'Entity') => res.json(404, {
            error: 'NotFound', error_message: `${entity} not found`
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so good at ES6 but I guess that it may be the javascript's context problem (I mean the `this` variable).

In your case, `res.json()` may throw `res is not defined` (I guess) since the `this` at that moment is the context of `export const to_end ...` (thanks to `=>`'s magic), which does not know what is `res`.

Sorry for my terribly bad explanation :(. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to understand more about `this`.

We can make things simpler:

```
module.exports = function(res) {
  return {
    NotFound: function() {
      res.json(404, {
        error: 'NotFound', 
        error_message: `${entity} not found`
      });
    }
  }
};
```

P/S: Not tested yet. Good luck! :)